# GridView Loses DataKeys

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Why is it that when I try to set my GridView's sorting using session states that suddenly my GridView no longer has DataKeys? All I did was put the following code into my Page_Init;

```
Dim SortDirection As String = Session("SortDir")
Dim sortExpression As String = Session("SortExp")
If Not SortDirection Is Nothing AndAlso Not sortExpression Is Nothing Then
    If (SortDirection = "asc") Then
        GridView1.Sort(sortExpression, WebControls.SortDirection.Ascending)
    Else
        GridView1.Sort(sortExpression, WebControls.SortDirection.Descending)
    End If
End If
```

But if I comment this out than my other methods don't crash out any more as my GridView now has it's DataKeys. Why is this?

**UPDATE**

This is the exact line that stops working when the above code is in place.

```
Dim UserID = GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString
```

According to debugger GridView1 has columns but it's DataKeys Count is 0. The error I receive is;

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

Comment: What is the error you get when your other methods crash?  What actions are you performing that causes the errors?

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to perform those actions in the `Page_Load` (possibly in a `If Not Page.IsPostBack` block) event, not in the `Page_Init` event.  Init is for *initializing* or *reading* control properties; Load is where you generally *set* properties (like sort direction, etc).

Basically, your `ViewState` hasn't been loaded in `Page_Init` yet.  So, you modify the controls properties in `Init`, then some properties get filled out from the ViewState, and this leads to unexpected behavior when your Page does the `Load` event (which recursively calls each server control's `Load` event).

You can read all about this (somewhat confusing) topic on MSDN: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: Having it in the Page_Load event was causing some confusing behaviour (also tried the PreRender which was worse). Put it back in the Page_Load with a `If Not Page.IsPostBack` and works much better now. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @killianmcc No problem, glad I could help.  That `If Not Page.IsPostBack` block causes the code to be only run once (the first time the page loads), rather than every time that page posts back to the server.